# Install MariaDB in Windows subsystem Linux (WSL)

Tags: mariadb, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to start MariaDB in the windows linux subsystem using

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
sudo service mysql start
```

but getting the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2 "No such file or directory")
```

I know, this is not a new question, I read a lot about other solutions under Ubuntu to fix this, but nothing worked so far. Has anybody an idea how to get it going?

Merci A

Comment: Sites: 1. https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/1282 2. https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/67

Comment: Use TCP/IP, not socket.

Answer (score 24):

I'm encountered with the same problem. Fortunately I found a solution at https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/745#issuecomment-237412792

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

which works for me. Hope it works for you too.

Comment: I am getting "sudo: /etc/init.d/mysql: command not found". I installed based on the instructions here: https://computingforgeeks.com/install-mariadb-10-on-ubuntu-18-04-and-centos-7/. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Question asks about mariadb, this worked for me: sudo /etc/init.d/mariadb start . didn't want to copy @cybercser.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have already installed SQL on your Windows system?
Try to remove them and install MariaDB on WSL only

Comment: Do you have any reference that the issue is caused due to install on windows system. Please give more context around your answer, answers based on guesses are of limited use.

Comment: I had same problem yesterday. So I tried many solutions about this problem. As the comment mentioned earlier, we can bypass the problem by using -h flag. but I want to solve the problem run mysql using socket. And I thought the problem is caused by preoccupied socket by windows system. as WSL uses many protocols of windows. so I deleted MariaDB from windows and the problem solved. I can use MariaDB with socket now

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now, might be better if you put the explanation in the answer too, it would help people looking for answers

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem starting MariaDB installed on an Ubuntu distro in WSL after already installing under the Windows host.

I found just stopping the Windows version was enough to enable the WSL Ubuntu version to run rather than having to uninstall the Windows version completely.

Answer (score 1):

The command `sudo service mariadb start` worked for me.

`lsb_release -a` output:

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)
Release:        11
Codename:       bullseye
```

Answer (score 0):

this post seems to be a little bit older but maybe it will help.
I installed a MariaDB on Debian 10 (WSL) and ran into the same problem.

After a little bit of research i noticed that the mysql service wasn't running.

with /etc/init.d/mysql start i start / restart the service and voila everything fine.

Hint: Have to do it after each Systemrestart!